# Legend sometimes has duplicate values

Tags: python, matplotlib

so I just have one item in legend being 'Average cases per day' however about 50% of the time I will see two items (duplicate), it seems more like a bug than an actual error. Also before i run this code again I have written a script to delete any 'corona_plot.png' if it already exists to stop any overwrite issues

````
    plt.plot(Date, Numbers, color="#6C969D")
    plt.axhline(y=Average, linestyle="--", color='#FF3A20', label='Average Cases per Day')
    plt.legend(numpoints=1)
    ax = plt.gca()
    # ax.set_facecolor('#B6C9BB')
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    plt.ylabel('Number of Patients')
    # plt.xlabel('Day')
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.title('Pattern of Discovered Patients')
    # plt.show()
    plt.savefig('corona_plot.png')```
````

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I have used the line plt.close() looks like for some reason for each iteration I run that code the Legend would stackup